# how to verify links in a PDF file

Tags: linux, pdf, hyperlink, utility, verify

I have a PDF file which I want to verify whether the links in that are proper. Proper in the sense - all URLs specified are linked to web pages and nothing is broken. I am looking for a simple utility or a script which can do it easily ?!

Example:

```
$ testlinks my.pdf
There are 2348 links in this pdf.
2322 links are proper.
Remaining broken links and page numbers in which it appears are logged in brokenlinks.txt
```

I have no idea of whether something like that exists, so googled & searched in stackoverflow also. But did not find anything useful yet. So would like to anyone has any idea about it !

Updated: to make the question clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest first using the linux command line utility 'pdftotext' - you can find the man page:

[pdftotext man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext)

The utility is part of the Xpdf collection of PDF processing tools, available on most linux distributions. See http://foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html.

Once installed, you could process the PDF file through pdftotext:

```
pdftotext file.pdf file.txt
```

Once processed, a simple perl script that searched the resulting text file for http URLs, and retrieved them using [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.03/lib/LWP/Simple.pm). LWP::Simple->get('http://...') will allow you to validate the URLs with a code snippet such as:

```
use LWP::Simple;
$content = get("http://www.sn.no/");
die "Couldn't get it!" unless defined $content;
```

That would accomplish what you want to do, I think. There are plenty of resources on how to write regular expressions to match http URLs, but a very simple one would look like this:

```
m/http[^\s]+/i
```

"http followed by one or more not-space characters" - assuming the URLs are property URL encoded.

Comment: thanks anyway, I will write my own script with these utilities then !

Comment: @user379997: would you post that script?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`pdf-link-checker`](https://bootlin.com/blog/pdf-link-checker/)

> **pdf-link-checker** is a simple tool that parses a PDF document and checks for broken hyperlinks. It does this by sending simple HTTP requests to each link found in a given document.

To install it with [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/):

```
pip install pdf-link-checker
```

Unfortunately, one dependency (`pdfminer`) is broken. To fix it:

```
pip uninstall pdfminer
pip install pdfminer==20110515
```

Comment: The note about pdfminer saved my day

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work currently under Python 3.7. Generates syntax error.

Comment: I added a new answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77936112 with a tool by the same name which works correctly

Answer (score 1):

There are two lines of enquiry with your question.

Are you looking for regex verification that the link contains key information such as http:// and valid TLD codes? If so I'm sure a regex expert will drop by, or have a look at [regexlib.com](http://regexlib.com) which contains lots of existing regex for dealing with URLs.

Or are you wanting to verify that a website exists then I would recommend [Python + Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) as you could script out checks to see if websites exist and don't return error codes.

It's a task which I'm currently undertaking for pretty much the same purpose at work. We have about 54k links to get processed automatically.

Comment: my question is to verify whether the links are not broken ! Thanks. I've updated the question properly.

Comment: Are broken links defined as incorrect http syntax or HTTP errors when you reach them?

Comment: Can you give examples of such page errors? I would defiantly recommend you to use Requests and see what logic you can apply to the response from the HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Collect links by:
   enumerating links using API, or dumping as text and linkifying the result, or saving as html [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html).
2. Make requests to check them:
   there are plethora of options depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42178474/1587329's advice was inspiration to write this simple tool (see [gist](https://gist.github.com/serv-inc/0405594483a4115233f47ab19cfbf3b2)):

```
'''loads pdf file in sys.argv[1], extracts URLs, tries to load each URL'''
import urllib
import sys

import PyPDF2

# credits to stackoverflow.com/questions/27744210
def extract_urls(filename):
    '''extracts all urls from filename'''
    PDFFile = open(filename,'rb')
    PDF = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PDFFile)
    pages = PDF.getNumPages()

    key = '/Annots'
    uri = '/URI'
    ank = '/A'

    for page in range(pages):
        pageSliced = PDF.getPage(page)
        pageObject = pageSliced.getObject()
        if pageObject.has_key(key):
            ann = pageObject[key]
            for a in ann:
                u = a.getObject()
                if u[ank].has_key(uri):
                    yield u[ank][uri]


def check_http_url(url):
    urllib.urlopen(url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for url in extract_urls(sys.argv[1]):
        check_http_url(url)
```

Save to `filename.py`, run as `python filename.py pdfname.pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [`pdf_link_check.py`](https://github.com/mattbriggs/pdf-link-checker) which does this and worked fine for me. It actually ran correctly, unlike the `pdf-link-checker` that you get when running `pip install pdf-link-checker`.